Why do I received a "invalid byte sequence " when calling a function through pg_background (encoding WIN1252)?
I am encountering a character encoding issue when using the pg_background extension for PostgreSQL.
The issue occurs in a Windows/PostgreSQL 15 environment, with the raise notice statement.
To explain the problem, a minimal example using psql will be more illustrative than a detailed explanation.
The encodings are as follows:
select current_setting('client_encoding'), current_setting('server_encoding');
 current_setting | current_setting
-----------------+-----------------
 WIN1252         | UTF8
(1 row)

Create the following two functions:
create or replace function test_encoding_1() returns text language plpgsql as $$ begin raise notice 'Noël'; return 'Noël'; end $$;
create or replace function test_encoding_2() returns text language plpgsql as $$ begin return 'Noël'; end $$;

A direct call to the first function does not cause any issues (nor does the second function, for that matter):
select test_encoding_1();
NOTICE:  Noël
 test_encoding_1
-----------------
 Noël
(1 row)

A call through pg_background fails with the first function, whereas with the second function everything works fine.
select r from pg_background_result(pg_background_launch('select test_encoding_1()')) as t(r text);
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xeb 0x6c

select r from pg_background_result(pg_background_launch('select test_encoding_2()')) as t(r text);
  r
------
 Noël
(1 row)

If we change the client encoding, the crash no longer occurs, but the characters obtained are not in the correct set:
set client_encoding to 'SQL_ASCII';

select r from pg_background_result(pg_background_launch('select test_encoding_1()')) as t(r text);
NOTICE:  NoÃ«l
   r
-------
 NoÃ«l
(1 row)

select r from pg_background_result(pg_background_launch('select test_encoding_2()')) as t(r text);
   r
-------
 NoÃ«l
(1 row)

So my question is: Is there a way to obtain a result in the correct character set (WIN1252)? Either by configuring the server or by changing the function code? Or any other solution?

Notice that the encoding in the editor for Noël must be the encoding for Postgresql to read the SQL input.


Why are you using pg_background when postgres_fdw is available? 2) With current_setting('server_encoding') UTF8 you will not get a result in WIN1252 it will be in UTF8. 3) Are you sure pg_background is picking up the client_encoding value?


@AdrianKlaver 1) I use pg_background to work around the lack of an equivalent to Oracle's pragma autonomous_transaction statement in PostgreSQL. It's the solution I found on the Internet that seemed the simplest to implement.
2) With the server in UTF8, I receive text encoded in WIN1252 in all cases, except when using the raise notice statement invoked through pg_background.
3) I am not at all an expert in pg_background, which is why I am reaching out to the community. What I observe is that there is no encoding issue with the return of the function.

Seems to be pg_background issue Problem with client encoding for exception messages #37. What about autonomous_transaction do you really need and could it be handled another way?

@AdrianKlaver The use of an autonomous transaction is a fairly simple solution that allows committing within another transaction. Of course, there may be other solutions to the problem I'm encountering, which is much more complex than what's described here, where I’ve tried to present only a minimal reproducible case. As you might have guessed, this is part of a broader issue of PostgreSQL/Oracle compatibility. And indeed, if there is no solution to this encoding issue, I will have to explore other options.

@AdrianKlaver Thank you very much for taking the time to respond to me. It indeed seems that this is an issue on the pg_background side

This issue is resolved with pg_background 1.3.

Use the built-in dblink extension instead. It's just as simple: demo at db<>fiddle
create table test(val)as values(0::int),(1);

create extension dblink;
select dblink_connect('autonomous_transaction', 
                      'dbname='||current_database());

begin transaction 
  isolation level read committed;--current transaction sees changes committed by others
select * from test;




val




0


1



select dblink_exec('autonomous_transaction','insert into test values(3);');
select * from test;




val




0


1


3 the "autonomous transaction" added this



The change committed by "autonomous transaction" persists after rolling back the transaction which issued the command:
rollback;
select * from test;




val




0


1


3 still here



In this test, you can see it doesn't mind getting you the four Noëls.
select set_config('client_encoding','WIN1252',false) as client_encoding
     , current_setting('server_encoding') as server_encoding;




client_encoding
server_encoding




WIN1252
UTF8



create function test_encoding_1()returns text language plpgsql as 
  $f$ begin raise notice 'Noël'; return 'Noël'; end $f$;

create function test_encoding_2()returns text return 'Noël';

select test_encoding_1();




test_encoding_1




Noël



select test_encoding_2();




test_encoding_2




Noël



Also, you can dblink_connect('') with an empty string to get an unnamed connection with all-default settings.
create extension dblink;
select dblink_connect('');
select * from dblink('select test_encoding_1();')
              as d(test_encoding_1 text);




test_encoding_1




Noël



select * from dblink('select test_encoding_2();')
              as d(test_encoding_2 text);




test_encoding_2




Noël




Thanks for your answer and the time you sent on this issue.
The use of dblink was a solution implemented in the past, but it was abandoned in favor of pg_background due to connection rights issues. These problems may now be resolved, so I'll make other tests. But it'll take some times so I can't accept your answer right now.

After a few tests, it appears that the connection rights problem are still there. And it seems that raise notice messages do not pass through dblink.
As elegant as this solution is for only the minimum case presented here, it cannot be applied to the real problem.

@JoëlHecht Thanks for the follow-up. It does look like with dblink you can only pg_notify() then dblink_get_notify() if you don't mind getting messages only after finishing transactions, or write/read a temp table with messages. Both sound inconvenient if you're used to just reading the client log messages. As to the connection rights problem, do you have any links I could take a look at, to see what you're referring to?

Thank you for your proposal, but unfortunately, nothing is available online. The issue at hand is part of a much larger project where all SQL queries pass through a bottleneck where they are translated on the fly from Oracle syntax to PostgreSQL syntax. The process needs to be extremely generic, and it's difficult to explain all the constraints this entails here. The first one that comes to mind is that, for example, it is not guaranteed that the connected user (who is not known in advance) has superuser rights.
